# opscenter 5.0.1 agent connection fail

Tags: cassandra, agent, stomp, opscenter

opscenter agent can't connet to opscenter.

opscenter's agent.log show error like this. ( replace IP to XX)

```
INFO [pdp-loader] 2014-11-28 12:03:53,517 Attempting to load stored metric values.
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:03:54,814 failed connecting to <X.X.X.X>:61620:java.net.UnknownHostException: <X.X.X.X>
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:03:54,814 Reconnecting in 6s.
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:04:00,814 failed connecting to <X.X.X.X>:61620:java.net.UnknownHostException: <X.X.X.X>
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:04:00,814 Reconnecting in 14s.
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:04:14,818 failed connecting to <X.X.X.X>:61620:java.net.UnknownHostException: <X.X.X.X>
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:04:14,818 Reconnecting in 30s.
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:04:44,822 failed connecting to <X.X.X.X>:61620:java.net.UnknownHostException: <X.X.X.X>
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:04:44,822 Reconnecting in 62s.
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:05:46,826 failed connecting to <X.X.X.X>:61620:java.net.UnknownHostException: <X.X.X.X>
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:05:46,826 Reconnecting in 60s.
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:06:46,830 failed connecting to <X.X.X.X>:61620:java.net.UnknownHostException: <X.X.X.X>
```

and opscenterd.log has nothing special.

my config below.

**opscenter config.**

$cat opscenter-5.0.1/conf/opscenterd.conf

```
[webserver]
port = 8888
interface = 0.0.0.0

[logging]

[authentication]
enabled = False

[stat_reporter]

[agents]
use_ssl = False
```

**agent config.**

$ cat datastax-agent-5.0.1/conf/address.yaml

```
stomp_interface: <X.X.X.X>
use_ssl: 0
```

so I chekc port.

```
$netstat -an | grep 61620
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:61620               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

$ telnet X.X.X.X 61620
Trying X.X.X.X...
Connected to X.X.X.X.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

it seems ok.

but opscenter agent show me a error .. again and again and.....

```
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:05:46,826 Reconnecting in 60s.
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-11-28 12:06:46,830 failed connecting to <X.X.X.X>:61620:java.net.UnknownHostException: <X.X.X.X>
```

is addition ....

I'm running cassandra 2.1.2( 3 replica) on CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
and kernel:  2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64

anyone can help me?

Comment: The UnknownHostException is typically thrown when the OS can't resolve a hostname to a given IP.  The form in address.yaml should be `stomp_interface: 1.2.3.4`.  If you've include the `<` and `>` in your configuration, you should remove those and restart the agent.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a slightly different message in the OpsCenter diagnostic output:
ProcessingError while calling CreateClusterConfController: Unable to connect to cluster

However, I'm running Cassandra 2.1.2 and OpsCenter 5.0.1 as well, and I had trouble connecting to an existing cluster until I saw this in cassandra.yaml

```
listen_address
# You _must_ change this if you want multiple nodes to be able to communicate!
# Leaving it blank leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This
# will always do the Right Thing _if_ the node is properly configured
# (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the
# address associated with the hostname (it might not be).
```

It seems this includes OpsCenter. So I commented it out. I also commented out rpc_address, and let it auto-configure itself as well.

Please verify these settings, restart cassandra, and try connecting again through OpsCenter.